# react native - onLayout is not triggered

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a small problem with triggering rotation event in react-native.

I receive the error that `this.setState` is `undefined`. When I use `this.onLayout.bind(this)`, still nothing happend.

EDITED

**App**

```
const win = Dimensions.get('window');

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        height: win.height,
        width: win.width
    }
}

onLayout (e) {
    console.log(e);

    this.setState({
      height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
      width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
    })
}


render() {
   return <View style={[styles.container, {width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }]} onLayout={this.onLayout}>
      <WebView
        source={webapp2}
        originWhitelist={'["*"]'}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
        allowFileAccess={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        mixedContentMode='always'
      />
    </View>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

**index.html (webapp)**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #container, #test {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><h1>aaaa</h1>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also the event is not triggered when I use simple `<Text>`

Comment: Does your `console.log(e)` is triggered ?

Comment: Only on "init app" not when rotating.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a method like

```
onLayout (e) {
    console.log(e);

    this.setState({
      height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
      width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
    })
```

You have to bind it in constructor like :

```
this.onLayout = this.onLayout.bind(this)
```

Comment: Yes I tested it too, see the header of my post.

Comment: yes but let this on your constructor and check on the doc (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)  i think this is the same of native

Comment: Got it, still the same. nothing happens when rotate the phone.

Comment: more like : height: e.webLayout.height

Comment: Where do you mean? `e.nativeEvent` is `onLayout` object, so webLayout does not make sense I think.

Comment: You can to make an action with true or false that allows to change your value : https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/Xjoqwm?editors=0010 (be like)

Comment: Thank you, it worked for main view only (bar with time / signal is moved), but not for elements inside. I edited my post above with the current code. Any ideas what can happend?

Answer (score 0):

I had recently similar issue and I know what cause it but not how to resolve.

Here is a snack.expo example: [Link](https://snack.expo.io/HkOLholIB)

Try to uncomment

```
       /*   {
      width: width,
      height: height,
    }, */
```

an instantly onLayout stop running.

If you are using as style a value setted by an state and this state is updated by onLayout function, this is only triggered twice times.

I means, this looks incompatible or maybe somehow is possible manage it.

I'm begginer with React Native,

Do someone know something about this behavoir and how "to fix" it ?